# as3 Privacy dialog will be displayed till user accept

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm quite new to AS3 so take it easy on me ;) 
I'm working on a Flash application and it requires the use of the microphone. I got the Privacy dialog. So far so good.

One of the requirements for using the application is to accept Privacy dialog for using the mic. If the user denies the access to the mic, the application should display again the Privacy dialog.

So...How can I do to display the privacy dialog again and again till the user accept it?

As an example, in the airtime website, after registering with facebook, you get a Privacy Dialog. Clicking on the deny button will make to display another Privacy Dialog.

Updated: Here you can check my code.

```
public function SecurityDialog () {
        log("hello world");
        mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        if (mic != null) {
            log("microphone name: " + mic.name + ", muted: " + mic.muted);
            mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, this.onMicActivity); 
            mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus); 
            // Determine if the user has already allowed access for us
            if (mic.muted) {
                Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
            }
        }
        log("done");
    }
```

In the privacy dialog, if the user denies the access to the mic and click on the close button, the Privacy dialog should be displayed again. Do you know how can I do that?

Thanks again people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StatusEvent` wont help you since it only notifies if the user accepted or not the access to the webcam/mic. I've encountered the same problem a few months ago, and the final solution was to remove the SwfObject container DIV with jQuery, and embedd it again. Yes, its horrible, but I've not found a better solution yet.

Comment: But when do you remove the SwfObject container div and embed it again? I mean... you do that as a response to which event?

Comment: Sorry @kitimenpolku . You should add `StatusEvent` to your mic Object after you declared it with `getMicrophone()`. You can check if the user allow or denay on the `evt.code` property of the event or directly on the `mic.muted` property of your microphone. Here is a quick example on snipplr: http://snipplr.com/view/17557/

Comment: Yep, but that is telling me when the user is pushing the "allow" or "deny" radiobutton. At that moment, the Privacy dialog is still displayed on the screen. So I can react to events when the user is pushing the radiobuttons, but not when the user is closing the dialog.

Comment: @kitimenpolku ! Thats because you are opening the Privacy Dialog manually using `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);`, try letting flash open the dialog atomatically when you attach the mic and instead of radio buttons you'll get an "OK / CANCEL" dialog, wich ensures that the dialog is closed when the user fires the `StatusEvent`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already getting the SecurityPanel. The thing is that if you close it, then it is not displayed anymore. The first time that the user accesses to the website /x/y.html, that page contains a .swf file. That file has a call to Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY); . And that's okay the first time the user goes to that website. But if the user denies the use of the microphone... how can I display the SecurityPanel again? What´s the event that tells me that the user denied the use of the microphone and closed the Privacy dialog?

Comment: I've checked this and I could display the panel everytime I clicked a button (which executed this code). You can execute this and run timer that will check for status change and if it is not allowed than inform user that application requires this and give him button to open security settings - you can't be invasive so you should not re-open when user has closed that.